# Visual Studio Code Hello World in C Debug Function is not working Programm NullReferenceException:

Tags: c, json, ubuntu, debugging, visual-studio-code

I try to use the Debug Function from Visual Studio Code 1.30.1 on a Ubuntu 18.04.1 as debug extension I use C/C++ 0.20.1 from ms-vscode.cpptools.
I compiled the main.c with gcc -Wall -g main.c -o main

This is the code of the main.c

```
#include <stdio.h> 

int main ()
{
printf("Hello World\n");
}
```

The launch.json config

```
 {
 // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
 // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
 // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink   /?linkid=830387
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [

    {
        // for Linux
        "name": "gdb C",
        "type": "cppdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${workspaceRoot}/a.out",
        "args": [],
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
        "environment": [],
        "externalConsole": true,
        "MIMode": "gdb",
        //"preLaunchTask": "build cunit",
        "setupCommands": [
          {
            "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
            "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
            "ignoreFailures": true
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

When I start the debuger I get

```
Stopping due to fatal error: NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
```

Visual Studio Code Version:

Version: 1.30.1
Commit: dea8705087adb1b5e5ae1d9123278e178656186a
Date: 2018-12-18T18:07:32.870Z
Electron: 2.0.12
Chrome: 61.0.3163.100
Node.js: 8.9.3
V8: 6.1.534.41
OS: Linux x64 4.15.0-43-generic

tasks.json:

```
{
// See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
// for the documentation about the tasks.json format
"version": "2.0.0",
"tasks": [
    {
        "label": "Build C",
        "type": "shell",
        "group": {
            "kind": "build",
            "isDefault": true
        },
        //"command":"gcc -g main.c -std=c11 -Werror -Wall -lm"
        "command":"gcc -Wall -g main.c"
    }
]
}
```

Comment: is `gdb` installed and visible to the program?

Comment: Why mess with `json`?  you could just run `gdb` directly

Comment: why use `g++` tools for a C program?

Comment: Yes. it is installed and:gdb is already the newest version (8.1-0ubuntu3). How can I check the visibility?

Comment: *How can I check the visibility?*  'cd' to the directory containing your executable.  Then type `gdb`  If `gdb` runs, then it is visible.

Comment: @user3629249 from the [https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/blob/master/launch.md]

Indicates the underlying debugger being used. Must be cppvsdbg when using the Visual Studio Windows debugger, and cppdbg when using GDB or LLDB. This is automatically set to the correct value when the launch.json file is created.

Comment: @user3629249 yes gdb runs in the containing directory

Comment: strongly suggest not using `json` rather run `gdb` directly from the command line

Comment: I did the setup now exactly like this guy https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vg7g3GiYIwk and still get Stopping due to fatal error: NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: It looks like they have general a issue https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/811#issuecomment-308185399

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like in the version I have is a bug in the Software. You can set "externalConsole": false and the debug function is working (this is a workaround).